# jQuery Stop FadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am showing a div with Jquery on mouseover fadein and fadeout its working fine but i want when user drag his mouse on that div i want to stop it fadeout.

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function ShowToolTip(obj, _class,_ID) {
        var my_tooltip = $("#tooltip" + _ID);
        $(obj).removeAttr("title").mouseover(function () {
            my_tooltip.css({ opacity: 0.8, display: "none" }).fadeIn(400);
        }).mousemove(function (kmouse) {
            my_tooltip.css({ left: kmouse.pageX + 25, top: kmouse.pageY -my_tooltip.height() });
        }).mouseout(function () {
            my_tooltip.fadeOut(400);
        });

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming everu `obj` has it's own `"#tooltip" + _ID`:

```
function ShowToolTip(obj, _class,_ID) {
    var my_tooltip = $("#tooltip" + _ID);
    $(obj).removeAttr("title").mouseenter(function () {

        if(my_tooltip.data("closing") == "1") { // If closing
            my_tooltip.stop(true, true); //Stop closing animation
            my_tooltip.animate({ opacity: 0.8},0); //Show instantly
            my_tooltip.removeData("closing");
        } else { // if not closing
            my_tooltip.animate({ opacity: 0.8},400); //Fade in
        }
    }).mouseout(function () {
        my_tooltip.data("closing", "1"); //Flag that closing animation is running
        my_tooltip.fadeOut(400, function(){
            my_tooltip.removeData("closing"); //Fade out callback, remove flag
        });
    }).mousemove(function (kmouse) {
        my_tooltip.css({ left: kmouse.pageX + 25, top: kmouse.pageY -my_tooltip.height() });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery [.stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function:

`my_tooltip.stop();`

From the doc above:

> When .stop() is called on an element, the currently-running animation
>   (if any) is immediately stopped